# How to calculate the limit of $\frac{a_n}{n^2}$ for the sequence $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{2 a_{n-1}}{n+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Assume $\{a_n\}$is a sequence which  satisfies the following recursion formula:
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{2a_{n-1}}{n+1}~(n\geqslant 1).$$
and $a_0=\pi,a_1=\pi^2 $.
How to compute $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{n^2}$?

Comment: For the OP: many users here tend to downvote so-called PSQs (Problem Statement Questions) like yours, and answers, too (some god will forgive them, but the poor human Jack won't). So it is in your (and community's) best interest to improve your actual question by adding some context (your attempts, why this question is relevant to you, something along these lines). Cheers.

Comment: I am voting for re-opening. A recent question was marked as a duplicate of the current one: it would make no sense to leave this question closed, too.

Answer (score 3):

Let we assume that
$$ f(x) = \pi+\pi^2 x +a_2 x^2+\ldots = \sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n \tag{1}$$
The recursion turns into the differential equation
$$\frac{f(x)-\pi-\pi^2 x}{x}=f(x)-\pi+\frac{2}{x}\int_{0}^{x}t\,f(t)\,dt \tag{2} $$
and assuming $G'(x)=x\,f(x)$, that leads to 
$$ f(x) = \frac{\pi(9-5\pi)}{4}\cdot\frac{e^{-2x}}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{\pi(\pi-1)}{4}\cdot\frac{2x^2-6x+5}{(1-x)^3} \tag{3}$$
so $f$ is a meromorphic function with a triple pole at $x=1$. By computing the MacLaurin expansion of $f(x)(1-x)^3$ at $x=1$, it follows that the wanted limit equals
$$ \frac{9\pi-5\pi^2}{8e^2}+\frac{\pi^2-\pi}{8}\approx \color{red}{0.4845}.\tag{4}$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Your method is to work out the generating function of series $a_n$ .It's a clever idea.The way I can think of is using Stolz's formula which is often an effective way of solving limit problems.While in this question I  was stuck in it.I have read through your reply carefully,but the crucial step,by using the fact that"f is a meromorphic function and 1 is a triple pole",how can you deduce the conclusion afterwards?It seems that you are saying "if $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-x)^3f(x)=c$,then $lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^2}=\frac{c}2$.Would you please tell me more details?

Comment: @mbfkk: that can be seen as a consequence of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_tauberian_theorem and the fact that for any entire function $g(x)$, $[x^n]\frac{g(x)}{1-x}$ is asymptotically constant, $[x^n]\frac{g(x)}{(1-x)^2}$ behaves like a linear polynomial in $n$ and $[x^n]\frac{g(x)}{(1-x)^3}$ behaves like a quadratic polynomial in $n$. For instance, $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}x^n.$$

Comment: Thanks again for your reminding!By referrence to the book named "the theory of functions"which is written by Tichmarsh,on page 242,Exercise 7,I've got it all.